# How to skip “Execute file” dialog in lubuntu and set default to "Run in terminal" (PCmanfm)

Tags: command-line, bash, lubuntu, pcmanfm

I want to run all the scripts (.sh) in a terminal and I don't want them to always open a pop up asking how I want to execute it. I saw [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/840600/1388077) answer which could have worked but it doesn't allow running in a terminal.

Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Comment: You've provided no OS & release details; however you should be aware that Lubuntu does not use `pcmanfm` any longer; it uses the more modern `pcmanfm-qt` which is a fork of the original program (maintained by the creator of the original program, ie. PCMan) so release details may help (or clarification as you've tagged a Lubuntu and now non-Lubuntu program)

Comment: @guiverc My OS is Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (Lubuntu)

Comment: Are you aware that flavors of Ubuntu only come with three years of supported life (five years applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server but not flavors), so you're asking about a release that is now EOL (*end-of-life*).  See https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/  https://lubuntu.me/bionic-5-released/ https://lubuntu.me/bionic-eol/  with support ending April-2021.   Use `ubuntu-support-status` on your system to confirm the supported/unsupported packages & act accordingly (ie. how important is security to you, are you offline etc?)